# Clean and smooth excel charts with VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I need to smooth and clean a ping data Charts (Orange on screenshot) for improve reading experiance.
- cleaning : is replace 1 ping as timeOut value by local average, but not many timeOut sucesively
- smoothing : is replacement of a small oscilating value by local average, but conserv the datetime of sudden change

[image: Ping/BandWith]

Answer (score 1):

I writ this VBA Code (Excel function Smoothing), past it in a new VBA module of your workbook and use it on your data series like this :

[image]

```
Public Function Smoothing(ByVal Values As range)
' il faudrait plutot chercher les valeurs aberante et les retirer
    AverageAvec = Application.Average(Values)
    EcartTypeAvec = Application.StDevP(Values)
    EcartTypeRef = EcartTypeAvec
    Smoothing = AverageAvec

    For Each cell In Values
        AverageSans = Application.Average(SetDifference(Values, cell))
        EcartTypeSans = Application.StDevP(SetDifference(Values, cell))
        If EcartTypeSans < EcartTypeRef Then
            EcartTypeRef = EcartTypeSans
            If EcartTypeAvec > EcartTypeRef * 1.3 Then
                Smoothing = AverageSans
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function

Function SetDifference(ByVal Rng1 As range, ByVal Rng2 As range) As range
On Error Resume Next

If Intersect(Rng1, Rng2) Is Nothing Then
    'if there is no common area then we will set both areas as result
    Set SetDifference = Union(Rng1, Rng2)
    'alternatively
    'set SetDifference = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

On Error GoTo 0
Dim aCell As range
For Each aCell In Rng1
    Dim Result As range
    If Application.Intersect(aCell, Rng2) Is Nothing Then
        If Result Is Nothing Then
            Set Result = aCell
        Else
            Set Result = Union(Result, aCell)
        End If
    End If
Next aCell
Set SetDifference = Result

End Function
```

My code search the value that have maximum impact on standard deviation, and exclude it for calculate the new local average.

[image: Orange is Smoothed]

it is a good implementation for 3 cells range, but `WARNING` with more cells range (for improve smoothing impact), if many value have an important impact on standard deviation only one has removed !

Comment: This code work, but is not perfect. have you an improove idea ?

Comment: Nope. But I have steaks and coconuts on my desk. Interested ?